# How to get the paragraph text from the xml of a wikipedia page VB.net

Tags: xml, regex, vb.net

A short bit of background to the problem: I'm working on a NLP (natural language processing) application in vb.net and I've decided to use Wikipedia as my training set of text.

I have downloaded Wikipedia as an XML file and I'm having trouble extracting plain text. I've been trying to work with regex to get the text of the paragraphs out of the xml file but it doens't seem to be working all that well. The issue I'm having is that when you view a wiki page (for example: [Anarchism on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism)) the internal links (to other wiki articles) just appear as the text but on the xml file they appear like this: [[Free association (communism and anarchism)|free association]]. I don't want the square brackets since this is just for the format of the links and I don't want the second page ID (free association) since that isn't how the text appears to a reader. There's also the issue of the  styles that I wouldn't want to remove (I'm pretty sure i can get rid of this with regex, I'm currently using`Dim expression As New Regex("/\<[a-z0-9\ ]+\>/")`.

To get the actual text from the xml file I'm using this:

```
Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("location of xml file")    

Do While (reader.Read())
                Select Case reader.NodeType
                    Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.
                         'code goes here
                End Select

Loop
```

I've been looking through the internet for help and I have found some helpful articles but so far my code still isn't working. Any help (even helpful links) would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if this would help and it's very different from your current method (hence only putting it in as a comment) - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/587458/GettingplusOnlyplusTheplusTextplusDisplayedplusOnp

Comment: @JohnBustos thanks for the quick reply! I've actually written my own 'only show the text from a webpage' already but since I've got the whole of wiki as a single xml file I'd rather no waste time downloading one page at a time.

Comment: Why not use a different source? Or, just copy/paste the article (from your browser) into a text document and use that.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 there are about 4 million pages on wiki so manually copying the text would be impracticable. Also I don't think there's a plain text download of wiki available!

Comment: Ah... I mistook your intentions. Perhaps you could download some plaintext versions of classic literature? See: http://www.gutenberg.org/

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I've used documents from gutenberg.org before for similar projects but I really like the idea of using wiki and wiki is likely to have a larger and more deserve corpus. Thanks for the input though.